# How to match the particular value in array

Tags: php

Im trying to match the array value. how can i match the below code ?

```
$os = array("CATEGORY=OS", "SYSTEM_NAME like '%A001%'", "CATEGORY=DB");
if (in_array("CATEGORY", $os)) {
    echo "Got it";
}
```

I need to match the `CATEGORY` in array how can i do that ?

**Edit 2**

```
where (CATEGORY = 'OS' AND SYSTEM_NAME like '%A001%' AND CATEGORY = 'DB' AND SYSTEM_NAME like '%A001%')
```

I have query something like this i need to replace the `AND` as `OR` before category occrence

**Expected Output**

```
where (CATEGORY = 'OS' AND SYSTEM_NAME like '%A001%' OR CATEGORY = 'DB' AND SYSTEM_NAME like '%A001%')
```

Comment: The question is not clear enough..., [I did't DV]

Comment: Thats a weird array, why not `'category' => 'os'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this preg_grep() php function

```
$os = array("CATEGORY=OS", "SYSTEM_NAME like '%A001%'", "CATEGORY=DB");
if (preg_grep("/CATEGORY/", $os)) {
   echo "Got it";
}
```

For more reference see [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php)

Comment: thanks for this answer. Can u please check my updated question ?